# How to Test & Prove my custom Map is thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I was recently asked in an interview to implement a thread safe implementation of Map class in java and assume that no thread safe library exists.

```
interface Map{
        void put(String key, String value);
        String get(String key);
        String delete(string key);
 }
```

I wrapped the HashMap and just made the functions synchronized.
Here is my implementation:

```
class MyMap{

     Map<String, String> map;

     public MyMap(){
           map = new HashMap<>();
     }

     public synchronized void put(String key, String value){
           map.put(key, value);
     }

     public String get(String key){
           return map.get(key);
     }

    public synchronized String delete(String key){
           return map.remove(key);
     }
```

}

While adding `synchronized` allows thread safety, I really don't know how to prove if this is correct or not.

I tried writing the following unit test but couldn't really convince that my map is thread safe as I don't know if the get will happen first or put will happen first.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(()->{ map.put("testKey1", "testValue1") });
Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{ map.put("testKey2", "testValue2") });

t1.start();
t2.start();

Thread t3 = new Thread(()->{ System.out.println(map.get("testKey1")) });
Thread t4 = new Thread(()->{ System.out.println(map.get("testKey2")) });

t3.start();
t4.start();
```

I saw the ConcurrentHashMap class' implementation and looks like they use Segments which are too complicated to tell in an interview.

Can someone suggest if my implementation is thread safe, and if yes how to have a test to prove it.

Comment: `get` method should be `synchronized` as well as other methods, if all methods are synchronized - it is thread safe

Comment: Assuming get is synchronized, how do I test or prove that its thread safe. Like a sample unit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone suggest if my implementation is thread safe ...

Your implementation is NOT thread-safe:

1. The `map` variable is not declared as `private final`.  That means that some other code could reach in and modify or even replace the wrapped `Map`.  This is (at least!) not thread-safe.  Arguably it is broken *irrespective* of thread-safety.
2. The `get` method accesses the `map` variable without synchronizing.  That means that there is no *happens before* relationship between (say) one thread writing to the `map` (via `put` or `delete`) and a second thread reading from it.  The lack of the *happens before* means that the writes are NOT guaranteed to (always) be visible to the reading thread.  That is a thread-safety bug.

The latter thread-safety bug could manifest as `get()` requests:

- getting stale values, or
- not getting a value for a key that should be present, or
- getting values for keys that have been deleted, or
- unexpected exceptions, or
- infinite loops(!).

An application that uses your `MyMap` class might work on some platforms and not others.   It might fail repeatably, or rarely in ways that are next to impossible to reproduce in a test environment.

---

> .... and if yes how to have a test to prove it.

You cannot *prove* that code is thread-safe by testing it.  You can only prove something is thread-safe by analyzing the code.  Depending on how rigorous a proof you require, even that can be difficult.

A suitably written test could demonstrate<sup>1</sup> that code is NOT thread-safe.  Basically, you need something that shows that the visibility problem (see above) actually manifests as incorrect behavior.  But the catch is that the 2nd flaw involves a behavior that arises from an absence of a guarantee.  The read operation is not *guaranteed* to see the previous write, but it might see it anyway.  This means that you could run the test on a broken implementation and observe that the test never fails on some platform.  In short, the test not failing doesn't *prove* anything.

How do you write a test for the above behavior?

Well one thread needs to updates on the `MyMap` and a second thread needs to perform reads.  And you need to design the test in such a way that the test will fail if the reader sees an incorrect `get` result.  But designing such a test is difficult because the test itself can trigger (for example) memory cache flushes that obscure the underlying effect you are looking for.  (For example, trace prints can do that.)

---

<sup>1 - Once again this is not a proof.  You have the problem that the testcase itself may be flawed and the supposed evidence of a counter-example to thread safety may therefore be bogus.</sup>

Comment: Assuming I make the map as private and final and make get synchronized, how to write a unit test to prove that this is thread safe.

Comment: See my update.  You can't.